# WPF web browser UI element refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

In C# WPF, I made a custom UI element that looks like a window so that I can have a mini-desktop environment in my WPF application. This "WindowControl" class has maximize, minimize, close, scaling, translation, etc...

This window UI contains a canvas, which is where other embedded UI elements goes. For example, I can embed a TreeView in the canvas of my WindowControl and move it around the screen just like as if you opened Windows Explorer in your OS.

Everything is working EXCEPT for the web browser. When I put the built-in web browser control into the canvas of my WindowControl class, it will NOT refresh. I DON'T mean refresh the url of the browser. I mean refresh the UI element itself. As I move my WindowControl class (with embedded web browser) around the screen, the web browser is leaving screen artifacts all over the place.

**THE ACTUAL QUESTION IS:** How do you force the built-in web browser UI element in C# WPF to re-draw itself so that it does not leave artifacts when being resized/translated?

I would include my code... but the WindowControl class alone is nearly 1000 lines, and that would not be pleasant on this forum.

So far I have tried the following (none worked):

```
webBrowser.Measure();
webBrowser.Arrange();

webBrowser.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { }));

webBrowser.Width = XX;
webBrowser.Height = XX;

webBrowser.ActualWidth = XX;
webBrowser.ActualHeight = XX;

// As sugguested by Noseratio
IntPtr hwnd;
((IOleWindow)webBrowser.Document).GetWindow(out hwnd);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);
```

Comment: If `UpdateWindow` alone didn't help, you can try preceding it with `InvalidateRect(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, false)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try forcing the update with [`UpdateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (untested):

1. Get `HWND` of `WebBrowser.Document` via [IOleWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IOleWindow.html)

   ```
   IntPtr hwnd;
   ((IOleWindow)_webBrowser.Document).GetWindow(out hwnd);
   ```
2. Call `UpdateWindow` via [p/invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.updatewindow):

   ```
   UpdateWindow(hwnd);
   ```

Comment: @user2984377, you can also try `RedrawWindow(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RDW_ERASE | RDW_INTERNALPAINT | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ERASENOW | RDW_UPDATENOW | RDW_ALLCHILDREN`) as a drastic replacement for `InvalidateRect` + `UpdateWindow`. See what combination of flags gives you the best result.

Answer (score 0):

**For WinForms:**

Error can't convert ...  'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' in 'PInvoke.NativeMethods.IOleWindow'

**Solution**

```
public IntPtr GetHandle()
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = Document;
        if (doc == null || doc.DomDocument == null) return IntPtr.Zero;

        IntPtr hwnd;
        ((NativeMethods.IOleWindow)(doc.DomDocument)).GetWindow(out hwnd);

        return hwnd;
    }
```